# Expand selected row RadGridView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, radgridview

I'm using nested `RadGridView` in my application. I need to expand the child grid/items on selecting the parent grid/row. As of now only if i click expand icon it does the functionality.

But for the user to view the child items i need to show them on selecting the row which means if the user clicks the `CheckBox` the row should expand.

```
<telerik:RadGridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  GroupRenderMode="Flat"
            GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8"  Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ClipboardPasteMode="None" ShowGroupPanel="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource ItemsViewModel}}"  RowHeight="30" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" IsFilteringAllowed="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                    <telerik:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                        <telerik:GridViewTableDefinition />
                    </telerik:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsRelease, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="75" EditTriggers="CellClick"  >
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Release" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" Width="55"/>
                                    <CheckBox Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="chkSelectAll" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding ReleaseIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource ItemsViewModel}}" IsThreeState="False" />
                                </Grid>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="chkReleaseItem" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsRelease, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CheckedChangeCommand, Source={StaticResource ItemsViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>

                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="No" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ItNo, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"  Width="Auto"/>
                    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate >

                        <DataTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadGridView GroupRenderMode="Flat" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                                         AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding NewItemList}" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsReadOnly="True"  AlternationCount="2" IsFilteringAllowed="False" >
                                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsSelect, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="75" EditTriggers="CellClick" >
                                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <TextBlock Text="Select" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" Width="55"/>
                                                <CheckBox Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="chkSelectAll" Command="{Binding CheckedAllItemChangeCommand, Source={StaticResource ItemsViewModel}}" IsThreeState="False">
                                                    <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:GridViewDataControl}" Path="DataContext.SelectAll" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                                    </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                                    <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiCommandConverter}">
                                                            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="chkSelectAll"/>
                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:GridViewDataControl}" Path="DataContext.PrototypeId"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                                </CheckBox>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>

                                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate >
                                                <CheckBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="chkSelect" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelect, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command="{Binding CheckedItemChangeCommand, Source={StaticResource ItemsViewModel}}" >
                                                    <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiCommandConverter}">
                                                            <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="chkSelect"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="PrototypeItemId"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="PrototypeId"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                                </CheckBox>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>

                                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Item No" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ItemNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Description" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Desc, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            </telerik:RadGridView>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadGridView.AlternateRowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#eae8ed"/>
                        </Style>
                    </telerik:RadGridView.AlternateRowStyle>
                </telerik:RadGridView>
```

How can i achieve this using `MVVM`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not versed in WPF but in WinForms you simply have to set the `IsExpanded` property of each row you want to expand.  A WinForms example is included.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/hierarchical-grid/how-to/expanding-all-rows